# Python tkinter - get value of toplevel field

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm fairly new to python, and am struggling with a problem with tkinter. I am attempting to create an application which has a main menu, with buttons to open child windows which will contain distinct functions. I can create child windows, but I'm having trouble getting the values entered in Entry widgets in the child window. I wrote a really simplified version (python 3):

```
from tkinter import (Frame, Label, Entry, StringVar, Toplevel, Tk, Button)


class main(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.master.minsize(width=250, height=250)
        self.master.title("main window")
        self.grid()

        newWindowButton = Button(self,
                                 text="open new window",
                                 command=self.newWindowOpen)
        newWindowButton.grid(row=0, column=0)

    def newWindowOpen(self):
        childWindow = Toplevel()
        childWindow.wm_title("child window")

        childWindow.itemLabel = Label(childWindow, text="Test Value")
        childWindow.itemVar = StringVar()
        childWindow.itemEntry = Entry(childWindow,
                                      textvariable=childWindow.itemVar)

        childWindow.itemLabel.grid(row=0, column=0)
        childWindow.itemEntry.grid(row=0, column=1)

        childWindow.submitButton = Button(childWindow,
                                          text="submit",
                                          command=self.submitTest)

        childWindow.submitButton.grid(row=1, column=0)

    def submitTest(self):
        value = self.itemVar.get()
        print(value)

root = Tk()
main_menu = main()
main_menu.mainloop()
```

This won't work, as submitTest is trying to get the value of 'main.itemVar', which of course doesn't exist.

I'm guessing the method submitTest is outside the scope of the childWindow widget, but I'm not sure how to pass the itemVar down appropriately. What's the correct way to do this?  Would I be better served creating the childWindow as it's own class, and creating new objects via the main menu?

For background, the child windows will be interacting with a database (sqlite), and all select / update functions will be self-contained in the child windows. The main menu's only function is to open the different parts of the application, it will never need to access the results of a child window directly.

Comment: In playing with this further, I've found that I 'can' solve this problem by making the child windows their own objects (inheriting the toplevel class) and writing the submitTest as a method of that object.  However, I would still like to know if my original problem is solvable without going that route.  I found that if I change the button command to be `command=self.submitTest(childWindow)`, and change the submitTest to `def submitTest(self, childWindow), value=childWindow.itemVar.get()`, I no longer get errors, but nothing prints. I'm not entirely sure why.

Comment: You can't write command=self.submitTest(childWindow), because in this case to comand will be assigned the result of calling. if you need to pass parameter, you should use lambda. Read more here  http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-callbacks.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it is possible in your application to create more that one childwindow. So you can't create one self.itemVar. You can create dict with instance of childwindow in key and instance of itemVar in value. And you can pass instance on childWindow in submitTest. And then you can access to corresponding itemVar

```
from tkinter import (Frame, Label, Entry, StringVar, Toplevel, Tk, Button)


class main(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.master.minsize(width=250, height=250)
        self.master.title("main window")
        self.grid()
        self.children_dict = dict()

        newWindowButton = Button(self,
                                 text="open new window",
                                 command=self.newWindowOpen)
        newWindowButton.grid(row=0, column=0)

    def newWindowOpen(self):
        childWindow = Toplevel()
        childWindow.wm_title("child window")

        childWindow.itemLabel = Label(childWindow, text="Test Value")
        childWindow.itemVar = StringVar()
        childWindow.itemEntry = Entry(childWindow,
                                      textvariable=childWindow.itemVar)

        self.children_dict[childWindow] = childWindow.itemVar
        childWindow.itemLabel.grid(row=0, column=0)
        childWindow.itemEntry.grid(row=0, column=1)

        childWindow.submitButton = Button(childWindow,
                                          text="submit",
                                          command=lambda: self.submitTest(childWindow))

        childWindow.submitButton.grid(row=1, column=0)

    def submitTest(self, childWindow):
        value = self.children_dict[childWindow].get()
        print(value)

root = Tk()
main_menu = main()
main_menu.mainloop()
```

Comment: I hadn't considered adding the child window objects to a dictionary, which is ironic considering an early adaptation of my actual program used a similar strategy for keeping track of objects. I noted in a comment on my original question that creating distinct classes for child windows will make more sense long-term, but this absolutely satisfies my "how does this work anyway" though.

Comment: In this particular example you can avoid using dict. Just pass to submitTest childWindow.itemVar and then get value directly from passed param